# creating sub table row under a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angular

I have a dynamic table that iterates on some data:

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of data; let i = index">
   <td (click)="addSubRow(row, i)"> + </td>
   <td>{{row.name}}</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to add under each `tr` a sub row, that in my case will contain a dynamic component:

```
<div #placeholder></div>
```

best solution I've got so far is having one extra `td` and using css:

html:

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let row of data; let i = index">
   <td (click)="addSubRow(row, i)"> + </td>
   <td>{{row.name}}</td>
   <td><div #placeholder></div></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

css:

```
tr {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
td {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
td:last-child {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
```

making it look like a row, but its screwing with my css to much.

option two was [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/N8Y6c/).

had some other solutions but they are not in the `angular 2+` spirit.

Would like to know the best approach for this case, and if my approach was somehow in the right direction as I'm new to the world of angular 2+.

Comment: the angular way is to do things like this in your view model - simply create a colleciton of subrow view model item in your "data" objects

Comment: use <ng-container *ngIf="...">. ng-container not add "extra" tag